# cy.clock and cy.tick not working with split code

Tags: reactjs, cypress, cypress-clock

Let's assume I have in my React.js project a `setInterval` which is a countdown from 15 to 0 seconds. However I want to make this process faster in the e2e tests, as 15 seconds could be 60, 120 or even 240 seconds.

So, this code works:

```js
describe('Test timer', () => {

  before(() => {
    cy.clock()
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
  })

  it('Displays timer, pass 15 seconds, does not display timer', () => {
    cy.get('div [data-cy=counterText]').should('have.text', '15');
    cy.tick(15000);
    cy.get('div [data-cy=counterText]').should('have.text', '0');
  })
})
```

However in projects I usually split some code like this:

```js
describe('Test timer', () => {

  before(() => {
    cy.clock()
  })

  it('Visit site', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
  })

  it('displays timer', () => {
    cy.get('div [data-cy=counterText]').should('have.text', '15');
  })

  it('does not display timer', () => {
    cy.tick(15000);
    cy.get('div [data-cy=counterText]').should('have.text', '0');
  })
})
```

Problem is, the code above gives me the following error message:

```
cy.tick() cannot be called without first calling cy.clock()
```

I tried to move `cy.clock()` to different places already but no success, so the question is: where should I place `cy.clock()` in the use case above?

I'm using Cypress 8.X, just in case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to preserve the [clock instance](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock#Access-the-clock-object-to-synchronously-move-time), as (I think) the cleardown between tests is affecting the pattern you are expecting.

You also need to turn off logging on the tick, as there's a bug within the logging code. (didn't dive too deep on that).

```js
describe('Test timer', () => {

  let clock
  before(() => {
    cy.clock().then(c => clock = c)
  })

  it('Visit site', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
  })

  it('displays timer', () => {
    cy.get('div [data-cy=counterText]').should('have.text', '15');
  })

  it('does not display timer', () => {
    clock.tick(15000, {log: false});
    cy.get('div [data-cy=counterText]').should('have.text', '0');
  })
})
```

---

**Simple app for testing**

```html
<div>
  <div id="counter" data-cy="counterText">15</div>
</div>
<script>
  let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    const div = document.getElementById('counter')
    const newText = +div.innerText - 1
    console.log(`setting ${newText}`)
    div.innerText = newText
    if (newText < 1) {
      clearInterval(intervalID)
    }
  }, 1000)
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. Using as you mentioned gives me an infinite loop of "Unexpected error". I didn't figure out what's wrong, but this doesn't seem to work.

I did not understand the `before` part, why are we setting clock to c?

Comment: It works with a simple HTML app with interval timer, behaves as you describe. I'll add it at the bottom for reference.

Comment: The `before()` is preserving the clock instance. You use `clock.tick()` instead of `cy.tick()`, where `clock` is the instance created in the `before()`.

Comment: Hi, it seems the problem was my machine. It works now. Thanks a lot for answer and good explanation!